# Email image replacement to reduce SPAM

Tags: email, image, spam

I'm creating a website that features a number of email addresses within the content.

The client is asking if we can set emails to be automatically converted into images, with hyperlinks behind the scenes, to reduce SPAM.

Firstly, does anyone know if there's a plugin or tool that can be used to do this?

Secondly, any thoughts on whether this is the best way to reduce the amount of SPAM coming to these email addresses?

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Answer (score 4):

The best way to fight with email spam is to have good spam filters :)

*set emails to be automatically converted into images, with hyperlinks beneath*

Spiders is not looking on visible text only but on hyperlinks also, so is not enough to replace text only.

You can try [MD Spam Me Not](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/md-spam-me-not) or [Obfuscatee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/obfuscatee) - this addons is do emails obfuscation.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts (and your edit) Max, much appreciated!